# Jetpack Compose, fetch and add more items to LazyColumn using StateFlow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

I'm have a `LazyColumn` that renders a list of items. However, I now want  to fetch more items to add to my lazy list. I don't want to re-render items that have already been rendered in the `LazyColumn`, I just want to add the new items.

How do I do this with a `StateFlow`? I need to pass a `page` String to fetch the next group of items, but how do I pass a page into the `repository.getContent()` method?

```kotlin
class FeedViewModel(
    private val resources: Resources,
    private val repository: FeedRepository
) : ViewModel() {

// I need to pass a parameter to `repository.getContent()` to get the next block of items

    private val _uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = repository.getContent()
        .map { content ->
            UiState.Ready(content)
        }.catch { cause ->
            UiState.Error(cause.message ?: resources.getString(R.string.error_generic))
        }.stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(stopTimeoutMillis = SUBSCRIBE_TIMEOUT_FOR_CONFIG_CHANGE),
            initialValue = UiState.Loading
        )
    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState>
        get() = _uiState
```

And in my UI, I have this code to observe the flow and render the `LazyColumn`:

```kotlin
    val lifecycleAwareUiStateFlow: Flow<UiState> = remember(viewModel.uiState, lifecycleOwner) {
        viewModel.uiState.flowWithLifecycle(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
    }

    val uiState: UiState by lifecycleAwareUiStateFlow.collectAsState(initial = UiState.Loading)

@Composable
fun FeedLazyColumn(
    posts: List<Post> = listOf(),
    scrollState: LazyListState
) {

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp),
        state = scrollState
    ) {
 
        // how to add more posts???
        items(items = posts) { post ->
            Card(post) 
        }
    }
}
```

I do realize there is a Paging library for Compose, but I'm trying to implement something similar, except the user is in charge of whether or not to load next items.

This is the desired behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding the new posts to the old posts before emitting it. See comments below for the relevant lines.

```kotlin
private val _content = MutableStateFlow<Content>(Content())
    private val _uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = repository.getContent()
        .mapLatest { content ->
            _content.value = _content.value + content // ADDED THIS
            UiState.Ready(_content.value)
        }.catch { cause ->
            UiState.Error(cause.message ?: resources.getString(R.string.error_generic))
        }.stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(stopTimeoutMillis = SUBSCRIBE_TIMEOUT_FOR_CONFIG_CHANGE),
            initialValue = UiState.Loading
        )

private operator fun Content.plus(content: Content): Content = Content(
    posts = this.posts + content.posts,
    youTubeNextPageToken = content.youTubeNextPageToken
)
```

```kotlin
class YouTubeDataSource(private val apiService: YouTubeApiService) :
    RemoteDataSource<YouTubeResponse> {

    private val nextPageToken = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)

    fun setNextPageToken(nextPageToken: String) {
        this.nextPageToken.value = nextPageToken
    }

    override fun getContent(): Flow<YouTubeResponse> = flow {
        // retrigger emit when nextPageToken changes
        nextPageToken.collect {
            emit(apiService.getYouTubeSnippets(it))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]